# JQuery Apple like slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question related to a JQuery topic. I am using a JQuery slider, as shown in this [link](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/11/beautiful-apple-gallery-slideshow/demo.html)
The navigation is controlled by the thumb images. Now I would like to create a link underneath the slider to control the scrolling images. I would like to change the position of the main picture, and the thumb picture position as well, what is used to navigate. Is it possible with a javascript; or do i need to configure a whole new event in my Jquery?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Find [here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/home.htm) and [setup code](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/home.html)

Comment: the links above are broken